# convert utc string to datetime

Tags: python, pandas

Try below code to convert utc string to datetinme but not work:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
    ["2023-09-13T19:17:21.000Z"],
    ["2023-09-13T19:18:22.000Z"],
    ["2023-09-13T19:19:23.000Z"],
    ]
    
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['ts'])
df['ts'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ts'],format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%Z')
print(df)
```

Comment: `to_datetime` recognizes the ISO8601 format automatically. Try just `pd.to_datetime(df1['ts'])`.

Comment: In any case the format string *is* wrong. `23.000` is seconds followed by milliseconds. The format doesn't include milliseconds. It should end in `%S.%f%Z`

Comment: but we need filter out not match lines as well.

Comment: What do you mean by that? The snippet you posted works just fine if you *remove* the format. The string is in the standard ISO8601 format. UTC isn't a format, it's the 00:00 offset, also represented by Z

Comment: Does the column contain mixed string? In that case `pd.NaT` is produced, which is treated the same as `na`. You can use `isna()` to find it or `fill_na` to replace it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why wouldn't this work?

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
    ["2023-09-13T19:17:21.000Z"],
    ["2023-09-13T19:18:22.000Z"],
    ["2023-09-13T19:19:23.000Z"],
]
    
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['ts'])
df['ts'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ts']) # remove the formatting used earlier
print(df)
```